# how to re-size image with border radius?

Tags: php, html, css

With my code when an image is uploaded, it is resized - works fine. But I want to resize it with border radius in a circle shape.

currently it only reshapes in 200x150 .

I want to reshape it like this

```
style="width:200;
       height:200;
       border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
       border-radius: 50%;
       box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); "
```

here is my index.php

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div style="margin-bottom: 15%; padding-left: 30%;">
  

   
 
 <input type="file" name="image2" class="file" id="imgInp"/>
   <span  id="topic-box">  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savepic"  >upload</button></span>
</div>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['savepic'])){
      $post_image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
      $image_tmp2 = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
      $kaboom = explode(".", $post_image2); // Split file name into an array using the dot
      $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
      move_uploaded_file($image_tmp2,"uploads/$post_image2");

   // ---------- Include Universal Image Resizing Function --------
include_once("reshape.php");
$target_file = "uploads/$post_image2";
$resized_file = "uploads/resized_$post_image2";
$wmax = 200;
$hmax = 150;
ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
// ----------- End Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
   }
   ?>
</form>
```

here is reshape.php

```html
<?php
// Function for resizing jpg, gif, or png image files
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account that you are shrinking the image by 20% but the border radius by 50%, I would try this line of code on the reshape.php

```
imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 50);
```